# Excel - VBA : Match with two combined cells?

Tags: excel, vba, match, string-comparison

my question is quite tricky so I'll try to make it as clear as possible.

In my program, I compare cells value with a database in order to find matches. 
The cells I am comparing are under a column format, with one word in each cell. The cells from my database, on the other hand, contain a whole sentence in a cell.

**For example**:   [image]

My program's goal is to find matches to identify a place. 
So far, here is what it is doing: it activates cell from the database and compare with each cell of "elementsListRange" which is a selection of elements from the column (so in my picture "B2:B7"). When there is a match, it adds a score of 12 on the line.

```
 'loop in the DATABASE
  For i = a To b
Range("B" & i).Activate

  'try to find a match btwn active cell and one of the elements from parsed address
For Each cell In elementsListRange.Cells

  If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value) Then
    Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 12
    Else
    Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 0
  End If
Next
```

So in this case, there is a match three times, with cell 1 (corporate), cell 2 (center) and cell 3 (building), which makes a total of 36 points.

**Here is what I want to do :** now, I want to make it more accurate by taking into account the position of words. So if the cell in the database is "Corporate Center Building", and the words Corporate/Center and Building appear in the same order, it would add more points. The idea is : If there is a match between active cell and cell 1 (Corporate), Then add 12 points and do another check : If match between active cell and cell 1 + cell 2 (Corporate Center), then add 10 additional points and do another If: If match between active cell and cell 1 + cell 2 + cell 3 (Corporate Center Building), add 15 additional point, and so on.

So it won't only find matches, but it will give importance to the position of words. So if the input is "Corporate Center Building" and you have both "Corporate Center Building" and "Building Corporate Center" in the database, the right match will be given more points.

**Something like this :**

```
'loop in the DATABASE
  For i = a To b
Range("B" & i).Activate

  'try to find a match btwn active cell and one of the elements from parsed address
For Each cell In elementsListRange.Cells

  If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value) Then
    Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 12

       If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value + cell.offest(1,0).Value) Then
       Range("K"&i).Value = Range("K"&i).Value + 10

              If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value + cell.offest(1,0).Value + cell.offset(2,0).Value) Then 
              ....  ..... ..... + 15 
              and so on

              Else
              End If

       Else
       End If

    Else
    Range("K" & i).Value = Range("K" & i).Value + 0
  End If
Next
```

**And finally, here is my question:**

Unfortunately, we can't write this this way :

```
 If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value + cell.offest(1,0).Value)
```

Do you know how to express this idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to join strings you have to use an ampersand `&` instead of the plus sign `+`, so to join the two values 
 `Cstr(cell.Value & cell.offest(1,0).Value)`.
The `+` is mostly used in mathematical operations like adding two numbers, increasing iterator, etc. 
The ampersand `&` is used to join strings together for example:

```
Dim stringA As String, stringB as String, finalString as String
stringA = "hello"
stringB = "world!"
finalString = stringA & " " & stringB
msgbox finalString
```

Now in your case you need to change the approach because what you think you are doing is not going work. 
Start with getting familiar with [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and [InStr()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php) functions. Split your sentence from the F ( database ) column to a Variant array. Then iterate through the B column to find the first match. If the match is found then see if the next word matches and score based on the results of the match.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, very useful. I tried this: If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value & cell.Offset(1,0).Value) and it indeed doesn't work well, it still doesn't recognize combination of words, meaning it will score even if just the second word is spotted and not the whole "word1 word2". I don't understand why when it's looking for a match "word1" it works, but for "word1 word2" it doesn't work. It's not that different...
I am gonna take a look at your other suggestion but I'm afraid it's too complicated for me, my database is huge and I don't know how to work with array, etc.

Comment: the concept of arrays its too hard - see [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link, will finish reading it after this message. It seems complicated although my idea is really simple. 
Here is what I have done: 
" Dim stringData() As Variable 
For i = a To b
Range("B" & i).Activate
stringData = Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")   " I now try to find a way to loop in the element of my array and use something similar to the offset to compare elements by elements.

Comment: `for i = lbound(stringData) to ubound(stringData) msgbox stringData(i) next i`

Comment: thanks! One last question and i'll have everything I need to program it. I used to have : "If Match(ActiveCell.Value, cell.Value) Then" Now, i'm not using ActiveCell.Value but the element of the array at a specific time. What is the way to call it? stringData.Value ? And in that case, would stringData.offset(1).Value would work to choose the next element?

Comment: use `stringData(i)` to access the value of the array and the offset will not work because the `i` works as your iterator. the arrays indexes hold the split value so in your case each word of sentence